# Setting default valhe for dropdown in ng-grid

Tags: angularjs, drop-down-menu, ng-grid, ui-grid

I'm having an angular  ng-grid with one coulmn has a drop down

```
    name: 'reportses[0].reportStatus.id',
    displayName: 'Status',
    width: '230',
    enableCellEdit: true,
    editableCellTemplate: 'ui-grid/dropdownEditor',
    cellFilter: 'mapReportStatus:this',
    editDropdownIdLabel: 'id',
    editDropdownValueLabel: 'value',
    editDropdownOptionsArray: vm.radStatusList
```

where

```
 vm.radList = {
      "code": 0,
      "message": "Total 3 records found",
      "result": [
        {
          "id": 10,
          "value": "Pending",
          "prevId": 9,
          "type": "R"
        },
        {
          "id": 11,
          "value": "Done",
          "prevId": 9,
          "type": "R"
        },
        {
          "id": 12,
          "value": "Reported",
          "prevId": 9,
          "type": "R"
        }
      ]
    }
```

I want to set a default value if no value is presnt for that(`reportses[0].reportStatus.id`)

Added this code on setting value for dropdown section

```
var defaultSpecimen = {};
        defaultSpecimen.id = Constants.ORDER_STATUS_PENDING;
        defaultSpecimen.value = Constants.PENDING;
        vm.radStatusList.push(defaultSpecimen);

        vm.gridOptions.columnDefs[4].editDropdownOptionsArray = vm.radStatusList;
```

But now the value is appearing twice.

[image]

Comment: show mw your html code also

Answer (score 0):

You are adding a new option to the list. Instead assign the one which needs to be displayed to the grid data source.

```
vm.gridOptions.columnDefs[4].editDropdownOptionsArray = vm.radStatusList[vm.radStatusList.indexOf(defaultSpecimen)];
```